# kotlin android studio Unable to figure out how to covert that text to double. Can somebody correct the code please?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, double

kotlin android studio Unable to figure out how to covert that text to double. Can somebody correct the code please?

that code gives an error -

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun String.toDouble(): Double defined in kotlin.text
  package com.example.termoparacalculator
```

---

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import 
com.example.termoparacalculator.databinding.ActivityMainBinding 

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private  lateinit var  binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.button.setOnClickListener{
        val inp = binding.input.text.toDouble()
        val temp = 2.0609 * inp + 25.748
        binding.textView2.text = temp
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? do you get any errors?

Comment: Keep in mind that if the value in the EditText is not a valid double (e.g. `"1..2.3"` or `""`) using `toDouble()` will throw an error. In that case you may want something like `val x = str.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input` is an EditText you need to do toString first

```
binding.input.text.toString().toDouble()
```

then make `temp` a string too when setting since its a double

```
binding.textView2.text = temp.toString()
```